# Lores keep on disappearing randomly in 1.13.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a map with my friend and for some reason we can't seem to figure this out. Randomly the lores on items keep on disappearing. I only got this to work when I open chests. I'm using optifine 1.13.2.

[image: Before]Before
[image: After]After

[Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ19r.jpg)

Comment: It was a bug to do with my game it wasn't mc I don't know how to delete stuff on here so I just made this comment...

Comment: Well, what was the solution? You shouldn't delete the question, instead you can post an answer.

Comment: Hi @DADp, If you know the solution you are able to respond to your own post. Detailed here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/